# Bracket notation for SQL not working in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm working on the following SQL Statement used in VBA, in a Microsoft Access application.

Our original code that works looks like this.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Standard Data] SELECT * FROM [Task Copy] WHERE [Route Step]='Example Step'"
```

Our problem is that we don't want the `ID` to be copied from `Standard Data`. So we want to do something like

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Standard Data] SELECT FirstCol,SecondCol FROM [Task Copy] WHERE [Route Step]='Example Step'"
```

This also works, the problem comes when we try to select a column with a space in it.
The code

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Standard Data] SELECT [Entry Date] FROM [Task Copy] WHERE [Route Step]='Example Step'"
```

Does not execute. When I click the button that triggers this code it never asks me to aprove the append to the table.

Is there something wrong with the formating of my last statement?

Comment: Does it work this way? -> `INSERT INTO [Standard Data] ([Entry Date]) SELECT [Entry Date] FROM [Task Copy] WHERE [Route Step]='Example Step'`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem like that changed anything :(
Thanks for the effort, though!

Comment: Have you confirmed the `SELECT` piece returns at least one row?  In the Access query designer, `SELECT Count(*) FROM [Task Copy] WHERE [Route Step]='Example Step'`

Comment: Actually your first comment was correct. My friend had modified the wrong button when he told me that didn't work. 

Submit that as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the destination field name.

```sql
INSERT INTO [Standard Data] ([Entry Date])
SELECT [Entry Date]
FROM [Task Copy]
WHERE [Route Step]='Example Step'
```

You confirmed that change was all you needed to make the `INSERT` work.

However, I suggest you use a different approach to execute the `INSERT`.  This will give you better feedback than `DoCmd.RunSQL` ...

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strInsert As String
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
strInsert = "INSERT INTO [Standard Data] ([Entry Date]) " & _
    "SELECT [Entry Date] FROM [Task Copy] WHERE [Route Step]='Example Step'"
Debug.Print strInsert '<- inspect this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
Debug.Print db.RecordsAffected & " row(s) added"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me how to enable warnings, it was so frustrating!

Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  That approach requires more code than  `DoCmd.RunSQL`, but it's worthwhile because it can make troubleshooting much easier and faster.  And I **never** run code with `SetWarnings` off (False) --- that suppresses useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this assuming you have the Database connection setup in Access:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[Standard Data] [(Entry Date)] SELECT [Entry Date] FROM dbo.[Task Copy]  WHERE dbo.[Task Copy].[Route Step] = 'Example Step';
```

Not sure why your SQL tables have spaces in them, I would redo them and make them one word like StandardData for example.

Comment: I agree completely about the name, sadly I inherited this :(

Comment: I believe you meant `([Entry Date])`, not `[(Entry Date)]`.